# Should simulator questions about operating an aircraft be on topic?

Tags: discussion

There's a question on the stack right now about how to [properly use the Boeing 707](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17140/how-to-set-and-hold-attitude-heading-in-captainsim-b707).  Granted, the pilot is doing this in a home simulator, but the questions is still about operating an aircraft.  If it were a real airplane, I don't think anyone would question if it should be on our stack.

This got me thinking, maybe some simulator based questions are okay.  Specifically questions about how to operate an aircraft that is modeled after a real life counterpart, so long as the questions is specifically about the operation of the craft itself.

---

This might be more easily explained with some sample questions:

**Good simulator questions:**

- What is the proper speed to land a Cessna 152 at?
- How do I start the engines on an Embraer-145?
- How do I adjust the speed of the prop on a Mooney Bravo?

*Notice these all look very much like they could be real questions, but the questioner will be asking them in regards to a simulator.*

**Bad simulator questions:**

- What is the best graphics card for X-Plane?
- Will there ever be a new version of Microsoft FS?
- Why did old version of Microsoft FS always start at (the former) Meirs Field?

All of these are particularly about commercial sims, and they may not be the best fit for this site.

---

Granted, with how much simulators are tied up into aviation these days I feel that one could make a compelling argument that we should try to answer *all* simulator questions.  But that's a little beyond the scope of my current question...

Any thoughts on if there may be some decent simulator questions out there?

Comment: @fooot And it appears that the "find questions like this" feature of SE has failed me yet again.  Good catch :)

Comment: I'll leave it hearee as a sign post though, just because...well, just because.

Comment: Yes, it's better to keep it *here* so that people will *hear* about it.

Comment: @Farhan *groan*

Comment: @JayCarr This question is really well-written. It's just that if you don't ask it in the same way, the "related" feature doesn't always find anything. You kind of have to know what you are looking for.